# Where do I go to investigate the Hanar Diplomat?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm currently investigating the possibility that one of the Hanar diplomats on the Citadel is indoctrinated. I scanned a terminal in the Embassies area, but all that turned up was a Hanar making large payments to its Mistress. I got a quest update to check its emails -- but I've looked all over, and I can't find it in the area.

Where do I go to read the Hanar's emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a terminal on the Docks: Refugee level that you need to access.

Answer (score 11):

For this quest, you need to access several terminals in succession:

- On the Citadel Embassies level, access the Spectre Terminal in the Spectre Office.  You'll have to authorize Jundum Bau's access.
- On the Citadel Embassies level, access the terminal near the "Office Suite" location - **outside** the office suite, on the right side of the door.
- On the Docks: Holding Area level, access the terminal near the "Security Checkpoint" - from the elevator, this terminal is on the **left** before the first security grid.
- On the Docks: Holding Area level, access the terminal near "Bay E28"
- On the Docks: Holding Area level, access the terminal near the "Security Checkpoint" - the same terminal as above.

Finally, return to the Citadel Embassies level, and Jundum Bau will be standing outside the Office Suite.

**UPDATE**: Some users are reporting that the quest is potentially [bugged](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/344/index/9687936/1) - make sure if you start this mission that you run it through to completion before doing anything else!

Comment: Hm... I can't seem to find the Acess Terminal near the Office Suite... (or at least nothing is active so I can click it...). Any tips?

Comment: @Holger, it's right outside the door to the Office Suite.

Comment: Be sure to activate the item on the spectre terminal. Just looking at it will not progress the quest line.

Comment: where exactly is the one near the security checkpoint?  I can't find it.

Comment: This quest is currently buggy. Once you've started the quest, if you do anything else the terminals stop hilighting. http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/344/index/9687936/1

Comment: Ok I thought it was bugged, there isn't even a door to the office suite (at least nothing I can open). The thing I think is a terminal looks kinda like an electrical box outside the office where the Hanar is

Comment: @Holger, the office suite is *always* closed - the only time you can get inside is at the very end of this quest.  The terminal's outside the doors on the right side.

Comment: ugh, looks like my quest is bugged too then

Comment: Ok I guess I'll have to wait for them to get the quest fixed then, thx

Comment: And now I seem to have moved past where I can't complete that (and another) quest... damn I hate that...

Comment: @agent86 I check all the consoles and there was nothing I could click on... but thanks

Comment: I can't believe this mission is still bugged.

Comment: Anybody looking for a fix for that bug can check out this: https://youtu.be/oblNr_NevDk

Answer (score 0):

There is one in the embassy area. then one in the security check point at the docks. There is also one all the way down past the holding areas at the docks on the right.