# Where are the terminals for the Hanar Diplomat mission?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I go to investigate the Hanar Diplomat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53600/where-do-i-go-to-investigate-the-hanar-diplomat)

I'm currently doing the Hanar Diplomat mission. I have spoken to the Salarian Spectre and activated the necessary overrides in Spectre control, but I cannot find any of the terminals.

Every time I think I have found one it just turns out to be an inert object.