# Hanar quest broken

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I go to investigate the Hanar Diplomat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53600/where-do-i-go-to-investigate-the-hanar-diplomat)

I was doing the Hanar diplomat quest when somehow I got the first terminal then activated the specter thing now I can't get any of the other terminals.

Is there a way to access the others terminal?

Comment: Err, that sucks man, but what's the question?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is a duplicate, but if it's not, it seems to be NARQ

Answer (score 0):

The other terminals are in the holding area.  It's a little confusing since the journal indicates they are all in the embassies.  The next terminal should be right off the elevator to the left.